# How to find all unique combinations of some small squares from a larger square

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Assume a large square that is made of 16 small squares (see Figure (a)). How to find all unique combinations of 4 squares from this? For example, Figure (a) and (b1) are two different combinations. However, Figure (b1), (b2) and (b3) are the same combination since their relative locations are same. Is there any efficient method to find all the unique combinations?

[image]

If we have to list all combinations, how to define a new combination that is different from the old ones, from a mathematical viewpoint? From my perspective, I think maybe we can define a distance matrix to describe the locations. For example, the distance matrixes of Figure (b1) and (b2) are

$$
X_{b1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
, Y_{b1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
X_{b2} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
, Y_{b2} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The question is, what is the criteria to judge these two combinations are identical based on these matrixes?